# Testing my ionic app with Instagram API on android device error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, angularjs, api, instagram, ionic-framework

I'm making an app using Ionic framework and AngularJS which uses Instagram API for login. In browser everything works fine when redirect_uri is my localhost.

But when I try to test it on Android ("ionic run android"), when Instagram redirects me back to my application it throws an error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for "localhost".

How can I test this on my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already installed Cordova's plugin 'InAppBrowser'?

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Check it out:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: Be careful if you are using "ng-cordova-oauth" library. Nowadays is broken. It does not work. I wrote to the author of the plugin reporting the bug and he told me, literally: "Apache introduced some breaking changes in the InAppBrowser and core framework. It will take me a bit of time to fix it. Localhost / non-existing web pages get piped into the loaderror event now, rather than loadstart. Quickest fix is to host your own callback so it doesn't fail to load."

Answer (score 0):

Need to give the app permissions to use the network connection.

Comment: I already have this two specified in my AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />